# MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback page directive not working with ajaxtoolkit control?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, postback

I getting issue with MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback with UpdataPanel in TestPage.aspx 
page. 
Page Header :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Abc.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" CodeFile="Testpage.aspx.cs" Inherits="Testpage"
    Title="Test Page" %>
```

I registered Ajaxtoolkit Control to my aspx page.
with

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxtoolkit" %>
```

When I add " MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" "page directive to my .aspx page
then I got the error message as shown in attached image.

[image]

Error: Status code returns from server:500

my Code

```
<asp:updatepanel id="upAnatomicalConfig" runat="server" updatemode="Conditional">                                        
<ContentTemplate>
<div id="divform" style="width: 98%; text-align: left; margin: 0 auto" class="W_B">
    <div>
        <asp:validationsummary id="valsum" runat="server" validationgroup="abc" showmessagebox="true"
            displaymode="BulletList" enableclientscript="true" showsummary="false" />
    </div>
    <!-- Here is some text box that I used for Save -------->
    <asp:button id="btnSave" runat="server" text="Save" cssclass="button" causesvalidation="true"
        validationgroup="abc" onclick="btnSave_Click" />
    &nbsp;
    <asp:button id="btnCancel" runat="server" text="Cancel" cssclass="button" onclick="btnCancel_Click"
        causesvalidation="false" />
    <asp:datagrid id="dtgrid" runat="server" width="100%" cssclass="dgGrid" onitemdatabound="dtgrid_ItemDataBound"
        cellpadding="2" autogeneratecolumns="false" showfooter="true" showheader="true"
        onitemcreated="dtgrid_ItemCreated" allowpaging="True" pagesize="25" allowcustompaging="True"
        gridlines="None" allowsorting="true" borderwidth="0px" borderstyle="None" onpageindexchanged="dtgrid_PageIndexChanged"
        onsortcommand="dtgrid_OnSortCommand">
    <Columns>                                                               
    <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderStyle-Width="5%" ItemStyle-Width="5%">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnEdit" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="ibtnEdit_Click"
            runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Edit.gif" ToolTip="Edit Template" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("tblID") %>'>
        </asp:ImageButton>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnDisc" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="ibtnDisc_Click"
            runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/inactive_record.gif" ToolTip="Move to inactive"
            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("tblID") %>'></asp:ImageButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>

</Columns>
</asp:datagrid>
</div>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSave" />
</Triggers>
 </asp:updatepanel>
```

What is the reason behind that?

Comment: Why are you so sure that the error is because of `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback` and `AJAXControlToolkit` combination?

Comment: Hi @NaveedButt , I tried with it.. When I added MaintainScro.... then It gives error message otherwise it works fine..

Comment: Did you try to debug the code? Paste some more code here for a better understanding...

Comment: Hi @NaveedButt , When I click on edit button from datagrid then I got the error message otherwise It works fine..

Comment: The ASPX looks fine. Kindly paste the `ibtnEdit_Click` function definition here as well along with any page life cycle overrides, like `Page_Load`, `Page_PreInit` etc.

Comment: @NaveedButt In page load just bind the Datagrid using dataTable and ibtnEdit_click event  protected void ibtnEdit_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        btnSave.Text = "Update";
        BindDataGrid(true);
    }  /****  thats all **/

Comment: That doesn't help anyway. I think the error is in your code, because nothing seems to be a problem. What version of .Net framework are you using. I will try and create a dummy application corresponding to that framework in my application and will see what happens...

Comment: I using framework 2.0 I think that y it comes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page directive - "**MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback**" not worked 
Reason is that 
 1) Framework 2.0 and 
 2) AjaxToolkit (ver 1.0.2....)  
 
 Reset Position after AJAX (async call) postback not supported.